# The footer on a website I just built looks the way I want it to on a monitor but on a laptop there are boxes around the footer and it looks incomplete

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble making the website look the same on my laptop and monitor but when I look at the website on my laptop the footer seems to malfunction and the footer looks entirely different depending on what screen I view it on.

What the website looks like on my laptop:

[image]

What the website looks like on my monitor:
[image]

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Adare Restaurant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

    <header>
        <img src="images/logo-adare-restaurant.png" alt="Logo for Adare Restaurant">
    </header>
    
    <nav>
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">MENU</a>
        <a href="#">ORDER ONLINE</a>
        <a href="#">GIFT VOUCHER</a>
        <a href="#">CATERING</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a> 
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h1>let's meat</h1>
        <p>We love sharing good food with great people. We bring over 30 years industry experience and passion to Adare. With a dishes that are carefully designed to bring you a truly satisfying Irish food experience that you are sure to remember.</p>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">MAKE RESERVATION</a> 
    </main>
    
    <footer>
        <p>
            Main St, Blackabbey, Adare, Co. Limerick - Copyright 2021©
        </p>
    </footer>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>

    html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #2f3035;
    background-image: url(images/background-adare-restaurant.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

header {
    height: 118px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.301);
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 240px;
    padding-right: 240px;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.301);
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 8px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 84px;
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}```
````

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but I saw you just asked a question and then deleted it immediately after receiving an answer. While I agree that the question wasn't stellar, you are robbing the person who helped you from earning any rep or recognition from the effort they put into their answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `px` for all your size unit. That would be fixed for all the screens. If you instead try using a variety of units, relative units like `%` for example would scale far better than absolute units.

See more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

You can use dev tools like Chrome's to view your page on different devices. See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/#viewport).

As a minimal example, i used `%` for your container's width here:

```css
body {
  background-color: #2f3035;
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/600/600);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

header {
  height: 118px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.301);
  height: 23px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 240px;
  padding-right: 240px;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.301);
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 8px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 84px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/100" alt="Logo for Adare Restaurant">
  </header>

  <nav>
    <a href="#">HOME</a>
    <a href="#">MENU</a>
    <a href="#">ORDER ONLINE</a>
    <a href="#">GIFT VOUCHER</a>
    <a href="#">CATERING</a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1>let's meat</h1>
    <p>We love sharing good food with great people. We bring over 30 years industry experience and passion to Adare. With a dishes that are carefully designed to bring you a truly satisfying Irish food experience that you are sure to remember.</p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">MAKE RESERVATION</a>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>
      Main St, Blackabbey, Adare, Co. Limerick - Copyright 2021©
    </p>
  </footer>

</div>
```